# Solr rangesearch within strings containing chains of characters

Tags: string, search, solr, range

I hope I find some Help. I'm pretty new to solr and had the oportunity to participate to a talk about it. 
For the following scenario even the consultant, who held the talk was unsure about, therefore I hope someone had the same problem.

I have a list of objects identified by a specific key. For examplepurpose: 
There are 500000 employees identified by id's (1-500000). Everyone of these people has to work for the next 2 years. Every day of these Years is identified by a character (employee will work - "A", employee won't be at work - "B"). So every employee got a String containing up to 730, but not every employee has the full amount of 730 characters (a specific employee joined the company later or something).

Example String for employee 256:

```
AABBAAABAAAABBAB
```

=> Employee 256 will work 2 days, 1 day he is not working, then he will work 3 days in a row, 1 day freetime, 4 days work, 2 days not at work, 1 day work, 1 day home and so on.

Example String for employee 542:

```
ABBAABABAAABAAAABABBAABAAAAABBABBABABBBABAABABBABABABBABAAAA
```

Example String for employee 2:

```
AAAABABBABABAAAABABABABABA
```

For dispositionpurposes I now want to get the employees who are 4 days in a row at work to go to dinner with them or whatever.

I want to receive the following results:

```
employee 256 4 days free after day 8
employee 542 4 days free after day 12, after day 23, after day 56
employee   2 4 days free after day 0, after day 12
```

---

I hope you got my problem. The example is only for a better imagination. Is it possible to implement a solution with solr? 
Other solution approaches (also for the day representation) are highly welcome. Right now we are dependent on the daily representation (every day has one character). But if you deliver me a high performance solution even this is discussable. The amount of entries (500000) is realisitic for the project.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify my understanding: for string `AABBAAABAAAABBAB`, you want to index it by all the days he worked (or not) continuously. e.g. `AA`, `BB`, `AAA`, `B`, `AAAA`, `BB`, `A`, `B`. Later you want to search the index by providing query like `AAAA`, which people who have worked for 4 continuous days.

Comment: Is it possible to index substrings of the whole string? I thought it is only possible to index the complete String `AABBAAABAAAABBAB`. But yes, you are right. Certainly I won't search everytime for 4 days. It can change for example to 14 or 42 days.

Comment: I am not sure any existing filter which can provide this functionality. But if you have requirement then you can implement your own filter which will generate the token as per requirement and use `RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter` for removing the duplicates.

Comment: Seems to be a good solution. But isn't it a bottleneck for the performance? I have to be sure, that the performance is guaranteed even with 500000 entries.

Comment: That's tricky part of it. I would suggest first look into one of the existing filter implementation and implement in similar fashion.

Comment: Just for completion: do you know any other concept implementing my logic with another format? So that it would maybe smarter to save the days in another format or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not model this as employees, but as availability. Perhaps with availability as a nested/child object of an employee. And availability object would then be StartDay,NumberOfDays.

The query then becomes a simpler join with condition on the child being NumberOfDays>=4.

Comment: With that approach I have the problem that only free days will be considered. What if I want to search for the next 3 days with state 'B' or what if I want to add a state 'C'.. That example with the employees is not a real problem, just a transfer of the concept of my real problem.

Comment: Then add a flag for the type of record. The point is, you need to represent *search domain* in Solr. And your search domain here is availability, not person. So, if your concept transfer is correct, you need to index at the higher level of granularity to take advantage of Solr. See Gilt's presentation for several takes on granularity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CiQatlZC0M